# Is it possible to dynamically populate HTML elements with XML data offline?

Tags: javascript, xml, offlineapps

I am currently making an offline web app that will dynamically populate drop down menu items using XML data. I am looking for suggestions on how best to approach this, given that local ajax calls are prohibited by most modern browsers. Unfortunately, it absolutely has to be offline. I am not sure if there is a way to do this with appcache, or if I should attempt to do it with XSLT and Xpath, etc. I am using jQuery for the styling, and would prefer to be able to use that, but can work around it if it is not compatible with the solution. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: where does the xml data come from?

Comment: Do you need the dropdown info to come from an XML document? Are you creating that document? I personally don’t like to use XML. It’s often to complicated for no reason.

Comment: Everything will be downloaded from a single host website. The xml data will come from an xml file that is to be downloaded with the other files. As far as I know, I will not be able to use javascript to retrieve the xml data and append it to the html if it is local.

Comment: I have already created the XML, but if there is a better way to do it I am flexible!

Comment: You can create a JSON file and read that from the server. Either way there is no need to download a file; be it XML or JSON. If you already understand XML and it easier for you to use then you should use that. Do you have any code written?

Comment: The app is strictly offline, so I am confused as to how there would be no need to download a file? And no, no code written yet (except for the XML and HTML) due to the fact that the first bit of script I wrote is what led me to discovering that local ajax calls are not possible/prohibited.